# where is the "ready" and "not ready" filtering based from in facebook custom audience?

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-ads-api

What is the "ready" and "not ready" filtering based from in facebook custom audience?. if you go to assets library of facebook business manager, go to "all audiences" , under the "audiences" tab, you'll see filters button, under that button there is a "ready" and "not ready" filter..where are these filters based from?, which status code are they based from ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a field "delivery_status". It should look like this in response:

```
"delivery_status": 
{
    "code": 200,
    "description": "This audience is ready for use."
}
```

or, for example, could be

```
"delivery_status": 
{
    "code": 300,
    "description": "Audiences must include at least 20 people to be used for ads."
}
```

To filter only "ready" audiences you can use filtering

```
&filtering=[{"field":"delivery_status.code","operator":"IN","value":[200]}]
```